# Implement a Job Delete button associated with a modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-blade

My logic is that if user push the yellow stop button then Modal box will show to get some user's comment before delete target job in the table as below image.

1. click the yellow delete button
2. Modal box pop up and user can insert some delete action comment.
3. submit clicked then that clicked job will delete in the table.

[image]

But problem is
for example, when I click stop button of job No.10 to delete job then Job No.1 was deleted instead of target job. It seems like always deleting first line of Job ID in the table.

How could i modify it?

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'cla'btn-group', 'id' => 'jobStop']) !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', [
    'type' => 'button',
    'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs',
    'data-toggle' => 'modal',
    'data-id' => 'jobStopButton',
    'data-target' => '#jobStopModal'                                
    ]) !!} 
{!! Form::hidden('stop_comment', $job->stop_comment, ['id' => 'jobComment']) !!} 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#jobStopButton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $("#jobStopModal").modal({
        show: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: true})
    });

$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
    let newStopComment = $('input#jobStopComment').val();
    $('#jobComment').val(newStopComment);
    $('#jobStopModal').modal('hide');
    $('#jobStop').submit();
});
```

**Modal HTML**

```
{{-- Modal box define start --}}
<div class="modal fade" id="jobStopModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure to stop work?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Kommentar:</p>
                <input type="text" id="jobStopComment">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Lukk</button>
                &nbsp;
                <span class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Lagre endringer</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
{{-- Modal box define end --}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the id of the  form you are submitting. This line: `$('#jobStop').submit();`. This will always select the first form with `#jobStop`. You should change it to a class `.jobStop` and use it to submit the **right  form**.
You can fix it following those steps:

First add a `data-job_id` to your button & add a class `.jobStopButton` (ids of html elements should be unique on the page).

```
{!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop jobStopButton"></i>', [
    'type' => 'button',
    'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs',
    'data-toggle' => 'modal',
    'data-id' => 'jobStopButton',
    'data-target' => '#jobStopModal',
    'data-job_id' => $job->id                                
]) !!}
```

Then in your javascript that shows the modal set:

```
$('.jobStopButton').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#jobStopModal").modal({
    show: true,
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: true
  })
  $("#jobStopModal").find('input[name="job_id"]').val($(this).data('job_id'));
});
```

***Note**: You should add a field in your modal with name `job_id`.*

Then when the button is saved you will be able to find the right form:

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
        let jobId = $("#jobStopModal").find('input[name="job_id"]').val();
    let form = $(".jobStopButton[data-job_id=\"" +job_id + "\"]").parents('form');
    let newStopComment = $('input#jobStopComment').val();
    form.find('.jobComment').val(newStopComment);
    $('#jobStopModal').modal('hide');
    form.submit();
});
```

***Another note:** You should also change the id of `#jobComment` to a class `.jobComment`, because they are also repeating.*

Hope that helps, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you for your accurate and critical answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Magnetic I have edited my answer with more details.

Comment: your modified not working and can't post Stopcomment to DB. could you give a correct modification? :(

Comment: when I test with all of your recommended code then modal not working so I couldn't input any comment too, thanks.
So I returned to my original code with your recommended point as just revise `.jobStop` then modal work fine, but post comment data didn't send to DB :(

Comment: could you check again where incorrect in your code? thanks. How could I revise Modal HTML? I made as `<input type="text" id="jobStopComment" name="job_id">`.

Comment: I got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: job_id is not defined` at `let form = $(".jobStopButton[data-job_id=\"" +job_id + "\"]").parents('form');`

Comment: replace `job_id` with `jobId`.